# EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached with Google Command Datasets

Tags: python, speech-recognition

When I tried to run the train.py file in Simple Audio Recognition
( https://github.com/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/r1/tutorials/sequences/audio_recognition.md )
I had some error here: EOFError: Compressed file ended before the end-of-stream marker was reached.
But I can't fix it. So, can you fix it for me?
Thank you so much!

This is link about my errors:
https://github.com/Cabbagehust2507/ASR/issues/2

Comment: it seems it has to download file which has 2GB. Maybe download it manually and change code to use local file instead of downloading it.

Comment: @furas thank you. I've just fixed it. The reason is --logdir default is "/tmp/..." so when I use Windows, it can't go to that address/direction, and when I fix it to my folder, it could run well. :)